# angularjs async issue. how to load data from another component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, settimeout

I have to use "set timeout" to get the data from the parent component, so I can load it onto the page before the

I wish to replace this with a promise or async function. But I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Here is the code:

```
angular.
  module('fwcForms').
  component('tableFreetext', {
    templateUrl: _formPath+'/fwc-form/components/table-freetext.template.html',
    bindings: {
      model: '=',
    },
    controller: function TableFreetextController() {
      var self = this;
      this.$onInit = function() {
        setTimeout(()=>{
          self.newValue = self.model.dataRowsPlaceholder;
        },1000);
      }
    }
  });
```

I wish to replace:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  self.newValue = self.model.dataRowsPlaceholder;
},1000);
```

With something like

```
let myPromise = new Promise(function() {
 return self.model.dataRowsPlaceholder
});

myPromise.then(data=>{
  self.newValue = self.model.dataRowsPlaceholder
});
```

But this does not work.
It keeps saying "self.model.dataRowsPlaceholder" is 'undefined'.

Comment: what happens when you do "something like" that - you say you can't get the syntax right, so show what you did, so you can learn why your syntax is wrong

Comment: "self.model.dataRowsPlaceholder" is from another component. When the current component loads, I can't put "self.model.dataRowsPlaceholder" on the page because it doesn't load fast enough.